# Cauchy sequence from Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and let $f_1,f_2,\ldots \in  L^1(\mathbb{R}),L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be such that $\|f_n-f\|_2\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Is it true that $\{\hat{f_n}(y)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ forms a Cauchy sequence, where $$\hat{f_n}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x)e^{-ixy}dx$$?

Comment: It is true and to show this, you should use the fact that the Fourier transform is unitary.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is true. It an easy consequence of young's inequality, which says $$\| \hat{f_{n}}-\hat{f} \|_{2}=\| f_{n}-f \|_{2}$$

Comment: edited, yes is true.

Comment: So from your equation I get $\|\hat{f_n}-\hat{f}\|_2\rightarrow 0$. But how does that imply anything about $\hat{f_n}(y)$? (i.e. evaluated at the particular value $y$)

Comment: I think you have the wrong idea, it is not pointwise cauchy... In that case, my answer is no.

Comment: Oh yes, I think you're right. I should ask for the whole function being Cauchy, not pointwise. But it would also be interesting to know about pointwise.